# Go offline to one person only in skype?

Tags: skype

So I have a friend on skype that keeps asking my to play video games, xbox, etc with him.

If I say "I don't feel like it" or anything like that he calls me and won't stop bugging me.

So is there a way to go *offline* (not block) to that user only?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that blocking a user makes you simply appear offline to them. You wouldn't be able to talk to them while they're blocked, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like the best way to go is to block the contact.

In this link that points to a thread in Skype Community you can find more information:

http://community.skype.com/t5/Mac/Appear-Offline-to-Some-but-Online-to-Others/td-p/18266

> in your case, you can temporarily block the contact/s whom you don't
>   want to see you online.  Blocked contacts will not be able to see the
>   status on the contact that blocked them.  Then you can just unblock
>   them anytime you wish to.  They will receive no notification or
>   whatsoever when you block them, so they will be clueless that you
>   blocked/unblocked them.
>
> If you need to block/unblock multiple
>   contacts, you can also place those contacts under a contact category.